# How to remove from vector string with letters only? My code does not remove every string I need to delete

Tags: c++, string, vector

In my application I have a vector of strings. In this vector I have various strings, and would like to remove from my vector strings that contain only letters. I wrote something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool lettersOnly(std::string text)
{
    for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(text.at(i)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void removeWordsWithLettersOnly(std::vector<std::string> &vec)
{
    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
    {
        std::string text = vec.at(i);
        if(lettersOnly(text))
            vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), text), vec.end());
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> vec;

    vec.push_back("Someletters");
    vec.push_back("Bomeletters");
    vec.push_back("someletters");
    vec.push_back("123456543");
    vec.push_back("098765");
    vec.push_back("someletters");
    vec.push_back("someletters");
    vec.push_back("someletters234567");

    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
        cout << vec[i] << "\n";

    cout << "\n\n\n";
    removeWordsWithLettersOnly(vec);

    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
        cout << vec[i] << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

The problem is, that ever I use my method on my vector, it does not remove every string it should. For my example code above, it does not remove the string `Bomeletters`. Why is that? This string has letters only, so should be removed to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is complicating things by removing elements from under your feet.

You can simply use `std::remove_if` with your predicate like this:

```
void removeWordsWithLettersOnly(std::vector<std::string> &vec)
{
  vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), lettersOnly), vec.end());
}
```

With that in place, your code works as expected.

Note that your `lettersOnly` predicate is making unnecessary copies of each string passed to it. You can fix this by making its parameter a `const` reference instead:

```
bool lettersOnly(const std::string& text) { /* as before */ }
```

Comment: Also replacing `lettersOnly` with `std::find_if_not(..., ::isalpha) == end`.

Comment: @chris or `std::all_of`

Comment: That would be better, wouldn't it :p

Comment: @chris both would still need to be used inside a unary predicate though. The simple loop solution doesn't look too bad (except that I just noticed it takes the string by value). A range based loop would prevent any loop index mistakes.

Comment: Ok, but what if I will need to pass argument to the `lettersOnly` function? (I would like to make a function which removes from my vector text with given sign). Something like this: http://pastie.org/private/fkeawivffyjzyq7gravgfw does not work.

Comment: @yak `std::remove_if` expects something taking a single `std::string` (or reference to one). So you would have to provide a functor that keeps the sign as state and applies the logic in an `bool operator()(const std::string&) const;`. Or, if you have C++11, do it all in a lambda expression. There are plenty of questions on both topics on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You are removing from the vector while iterating it.

for example:
When "Someletters" is deleted -> your vector is decreased in size and now "Bomeletters" is in position 0.  However your counter i is already at position 1 -> so "Bomeletters" is missed.

The simplest way to solve this is to just copy the non filtered strings to a new vector, then use "swap()" to replace the content of the 2 vectors.